# OAuthWebSecurity doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, webforms

I develop our application and allows the user to login via Facebook, Microsoft, Google, Twitter and LinkedIn.

In Globas.asax registering services:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = !HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled;
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery",
                new ScriptResourceDefinition
                {
                    Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
                    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"
                });

            this.RegisterAuthenticationProviders();
        }

        private void RegisterAuthenticationProviders()
        {
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient("key1", "key2", "Facebook");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient("Google");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterLinkedInClient("key1", "key2", "LinkedIn");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient("key1", "key2", "Microsoft");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient("key1", "key2", "Twitter");
        }
```

At the click of a button calls the appropriate method:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication("ServiceName", String.Format("~/Login.ashx"));
```

serviceNames are:Microsoft, Google, LinkedIn, Facebook or Twitter according to the button that is pressed.

Handler Login.aspx look like:

```
public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
            if (result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var service = (LoginServices)Enum.Parse(typeof(LoginServices), result.Provider, true);
                //Find user in DB, if not find create and login at last
                this.TryLogin(result, context, service);

                this.RedirectRequest(context);
            }
            else
            {
                // Login failed
                DBLogger.WriteLog(LogPriority.Fatal, String.Format("{0}-{1}_1", this.GetType().Name, "ProcessRequest"), result.Error);
                this.RedirectRequest(context, ErrorMessages.LoginFailed);
            }
    }
```

**Facebook**: is fine and everything is working correctly

**Microsoft**: redirect to login is fine, but in return I will return error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6442312
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.MicrosoftClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +334
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +142
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +239
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +129
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +86
   Login.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +18
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

**Google and LinkedIn**: Click on the link I report the javascript error: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0`

**Twitter** Click on the link I report the javascript error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

The buttons are  with register onclick envet in OnInit event in page.

Do you have any idea why my code does not work?
Thanks

### Update

Problem solved. It was all that was ImageButtons in UpdatePanel

Comment: Try to debug the requests with Fiddler, maybe it will give you more information in the response body on what went wrong. The current exception is very wide, you need to find out, if there is anything wrong with OAuth or something else..

Comment: Robert: Problem solved. It was all that was ImageButtons in <asp:UpdatePanel...

Answer (score 0):

For LinkedIn, just update package, it will work for sure.

> update-package DotNetOpenAuth.Core

hit 'Enter' and enjoy.